# Retrieve data from Firebase JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop a web application which allows the user to post notes (markers) on the map for others to read. It is basically placing markers on the map that consist of the subject and the message. It is accessed by clicking on a marker on the map.

Right now I am facing an issue with regards of retrieving the data from Firebase. I managed to make the application send data to Firebase (latitude and longitude for marker location on the map, and the message with the subject itself), but I am unable to take the information back in order to place a marker on the exact coordinates.

I followed many YouTube tutorials and online guides but the Firebase data won't show anywhere except for the console in Chrome.

Any clue what could be the issue? I am posting the JavaScript for he map and Firebase below so you can see how I saved message, subject, latitude and longitude to Firebase database.

Thanks

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var note = firebase.database().ref("note");

/*map*/
window.onload = getLocation;
var geo = navigator.geolocation;

function getLocation() {
    if (geo) {
        geo.watchPosition(displayLocation);
    }
    else {
        alert("opps, geolocation API is not supported ");
    }
}

function displayLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    /*diaplays coordinates in the footer of the webapp*/
    var div = document.getElementById( 'location' );
    longText = document.getElementById("longitude")
    if (latitude == latitude)
    {
        div.innerHTML = "X: " + latitude + " Y: " + longitude;
    }
}

/*map*/
var map, infoWindow;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 6,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    /*gets Navigation, sets the map to current position and posts a marker*/
    /*Shouldn't post a marker, code will be removed later when we learn how 
      to post markers to note locations rather than user locations*/
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
            };
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
            })
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                position: pos,
                map: map
            })   
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

/*stores Geolocation in local storage to call it later*/
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p)
{
    localStorage.setItem("latitude", p.coords.latitude);
    localStorage.setItem("longitude", p.coords.longitude);
}, function(e){console.log(e)})

 /*error handler obviously*/
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

/*button firebase function*/
var submitNote = function () {
        var subject = $("#messageSubject").val();
        var message = $("#messageContent").val();
        var lat = localStorage.latitude;
        var lon = localStorage.longitude;

        note.push({
            "subject": subject,
            "message": message,
            "latitude": lat,
            "longitude": lon
    });

};

$(window).load(function () {
    $("#noteForm").submit(submitNote);
});
```

Comment: Basically, a "note" is a regular marker you can place on a map. I called it a note because when you click on the marker it displays a message written by someone else.

I need to retrieve latitude and longitude that has been saved in the firebase then a user clicked the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the latitude and longitude from the database:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("markers").on('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var childData = child.val();
        var latitudes=child.val().latitude;
        var longitudes=child.val().longitude;
    });
});
```

Assuming the database is like this:

```
markers
   pushid
       subject: subject
       message: message
       latitude: lat
       longitude: lon
```